# cannot use yum since removing postfix

Tags: yum

yum remove postfix has made it so yum itself no longer works and neither does wget epel repository...nothing can be found.

In such a case is it better to re install Centos?

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
repo id                         repo name                             status
addons/7                        CentOS-7 - Addons                     enabled: 0
base/7                          CentOS-7 - Base                       enabled: 0
centosplus/7                    CentOS-7 - Plus                       enabled: 0
contrib/7                       CentOS-7 - Contrib                    disabled
extras/7                        CentOS-7 - Extras                     enabled: 0
updates/7                       CentOS-7 - Updates                    enabled: 0
repolist: 0


ID | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
85 | root <root>              | 2015-11-29 15:20 | Erase          |    2 EE
84 | root <root>              | 2015-11-29 15:20 | Erase          |    1   
83 | root <root>              | 2015-11-29 15:20 | Erase          |    1 EE
82 | root <root>              | 2015-11-29 11:28 | Erase          |    1   
81 | root <root>              | 2015-11-29 11:22 | Install        |    2   
80 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 11:16 | Install        |    1   
79 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 11:16 | Erase          |    1   
78 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 10:32 | Install        |    1   
77 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 10:09 | Install        |    1   
76 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 09:48 | Install        |    2   
75 | root <root>              | 2015-11-25 09:45 | I, U           |   47 EE
74 | root <root>              | 2015-11-24 18:58 | Erase          |    1   
73 | root <root>              | 2015-11-24 18:58 | Erase          |    1   
72 | root <root>              | 2015-11-24 17:18 | Install        |    1   
71 | root <root>              | 2015-11-24 17:16 | Install        |    1   
70 |  <me>                    | 2015-11-18 21:32 | Install        |    1   
69 | root <root>              | 2015-11-18 21:27 | Erase          |    1 EE
68 | root <root>              | 2015-11-18 19:50 | I, U           |    3   
67 | root <root>              | 2015-08-07 17:45 | Reinstall      |    1   
66 | root <root>              | 2015-08-03 19:57 | Install        |  127
```

Comment: What actual error message do you get when you run basic yum commands, like `yum check` or `yum repolist` ?

Comment: no mirror list found try and find upstream and reconfigure base url

Comment: have already tried yum clean all and tried reconfiguring files in yum.repos.d  - cannot even get epel rpm manually to try and force install. i think it is beyond repair and will have to start from scratch. I must have removed postfix while it was still on or something the repos did not like.

Comment: You are getting DNS resolution errors from `curl`, which may be unrelated (unless yum somehow removed something related to networking). Can you try `curl -I http://mirrorlist.centos.org/` and `nslookup mirrorlist.centos.org` and let us know what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your `DNS` as it is unable to locate your yum `repo` host and giving the error, try ping `google.com` to see your `DNS` is working or not

Comment: that's exactly what vps provider said so must be right but i ended up reinstalling and from now on using sudo